# Completing the Lost Patrol [BoS side] quest...?

Tags: fallout-4

I seem to be having a problem completing the Brotherhood of Steel sidequest Lost Patrol, and I'm wondering if I've hit a bug/if anyone knows how to workaround it/has experienced the same problem/etc.

Basically, I'm at the point where I'm supposed to report to Danse to complete the quest, but can't figure out how to get that dialogue option.

The longer version...

I stumbled onto the [Lost Patrol](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_Patrol) quest before even doing the first BoS quest, [Fire Support](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_Support). I ended up retrieving Knight Astlin's holotape (second one for this quest) and clearing the National Guard Training Yard as part of some sidequest to get a settlement to join me, still without doing [Fire Support](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_Support).

Eventually, I got back around to BoS quests, punching through [Fire Support](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_Support), then [Call to Arms](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Call_to_Arms), then the first iteration of both   [Cleansing the Commonwealth](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Cleansing_the_Commonwealth) and [Quartermastery](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Quartermastery).  Following that, I listened to the holotapes, pushed through and completed the quest,

> even convincing Paladin Brandis to rejoin the Brotherhood.

Now I have Report to Danse as the next quest objective... but I can't.  When I talk to him, I get forced into [Semper Invicta](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Semper_Invicta), and at every step between there and completing [Tour of Duty](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Tour_of_Duty), talking to him results in being told to go do the objective in the active quest in the BoS quest line, culminating as him being available as a companion.

And now that he's available as a companion, that seems to be the only dialogue option I get when I talk to him. I can either take him on, or tell him  not now, which ends the conversation. If I do take him on as a companion, I can't seem to trigger a way to report the quest to him, whether he's traveling with me, or is currently dismissed.

Am I missing something, or have I found a bug?  And does anyone have suggestions or similar experiences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue, but eventually Danse just suddenly started talking about the quest shortly after Brandis was found. Supposedly Captain Kells can also complete the quest, according to the Fallout 4 wiki:

> If the player character puts off completing this quest until after Paladin Danse has become a potential companion, they may be unable to turn the quest in as he will only offer companion dialogue options. However, after a period of time the mission turn in point will be transferred to Captain Kells, allowing for completion.

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_Patrol

Comment: D'oh.  Dunno how I missed that in the wikia, but thank you.  (I'm just waiting for that to happen before I accept this answer, FYI.)

Comment: I've hit similar issues with Preston and turning in Settlement help quests after he begins talking about retaking the Castle: Until you agree to the plan *and* meet up with him, he will only ask if you want to retake the castle.